# forecast using an ARIMA Model

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

[image]I'm using the R function `auto.arima` to fit an arima model for a time series, 
the result is an ARIMA(2,1,1). After that I apply the `forecast` function to predict some futur values. My question is Should I do the transformation ("un-differentiate" the predicted values) or is it done by `forecast` automatically ? 
edit : above is the plot I get when I execute the following code :

```
arimaf = auto.arima(timeseries)
pred = forecast(arimaf, h = 10)
plot(pred, main = "PREDICTION USING ARIMA(2,1,1)")
```

Comment: It's done automatically. Plot the actual values and the forecasts, and you will see that the latter nicely extend the former, there should be no big changes in the behaviour of the time series.

Comment: @RichardHardy Here is a plot of the time series + the forcast

Comment: OK, the latter does not nicely extend the former as it cannot capture all the wiggliness. But the answer is the same in any case: you do not need to manually undifference.

Comment: Your model is probably deficient as unusual values may have distorted the identification process. If you wish you can post our data and I will try and help you ( and others) as it relates to robust ARIMA model identification.